# How to add text boxes dynamically in asp.net C# and use the textbox values after adding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am able to add textboxes dynamically and i am not able to use the value of the textboxes which are dynamically added
 Here is my code

```
int i = 0;
List<string> controlidlist = new List<string>();
protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{
    base.LoadViewState(savedState);
    controlidlist = (List<string>)ViewState["controlidlist"];
    foreach (string Id in controlidlist)
    {
        i++;
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = Id;
        LiteralControl lineBreak = new LiteralControl();
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tb);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
    }
}
```

Here am performing the dynamically adding the textboxes

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    i++;
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.ID = "textboxes" + i;
    tb.Text = "textbox" + i;

    LiteralControl lineBreak = new LiteralControl("<br>");
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tb);
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
    controlidlist.Add(tb.ID);
    ViewState["controlidlist"] = controlidlist;

}
```

Here i want to try get the textbox values which are dynamically added

```
  protected void datainput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string m = string.Empty;
    for (int f = 0; f < i; f++)
    {
        TextBox t = (TextBox)FindControl("textboxes"+f);
        string k = t.Text;
        m = m +","+k;


        }
    string h = m;
}
```

The error which am getting is 
"**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**".
at **string k = t.Text;**

Answer (score 1):

Add it to a container:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlTextboxes"></asp:Panel>

 foreach (string Id in controlidlist)
    {
        i++;
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = Id;
        LiteralControl lineBreak = new LiteralControl();
        pnlTextboxes.Controls.Add(tb);
        pnlTextboxes.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
    }
```

and :

```
 TextBox t = (TextBox)pnlTextboxes.FindControl("textboxes"+f);
```

UPDATE:

```
TextBox t = (TextBox)PlaceHolder1.FindControl("textboxes"+f);
```

Comment: should i replace place holder and add it to the panel

Comment: if you are using placeholder then search it inside placeholder. see updated answer @user3630591